# TypeError: this is undefined while setting state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload file from reatjs to firebase storage. And I also wanted to save url in realtime database. I have uploaded the file and now i wanted to get file name to save in database. But while saving file name in variable with setState method it tells me this is undefined

```
     handleSubmitFirebase(event) {

        alert(this.state.avatarURL);
        var docInfo = {
            title: this.docnm.value,
            path: this.state.avatarURL,
            document_type: this.doc_type.value,
            unm: this.unm.value,
            D_id: DbConfig.database()
                .ref("documents")
                .push(docInfo).key
        }; //documents info

        DbConfig.database()
            .ref("documents")
            .push(docInfo);
        this.docnm.value = ""; // <- clear the input
        alert("Successfully Added");
    }
     handlePdfUploadSuccess(filename) {

        alert(filename);

        this.setState({ avatar: filename, progress: 100, isUploading: false }); //error line
        DbConfig.storage().ref('upload/').child(filename).getDownloadURL().then(url => this.setState({ avatarURL: url }));
    }

 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitFirebase}>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                        <label className="control-label">Document Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" ref={el => (this.docnm = el)} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                        <label className="control-label">Document type</label>
                                        <div className="room-main">
                                            <div className="online-est">
                                                <select className="room-form" ref={el => (this.doc_type = el)}>
                                                    <option value="Circular">Circular</option>
                                                    <option value="User">User</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                        <label className="control-label">User Name</label>
                                        <div className="room-main">
                                            <div className="online-est">
                                                <select className="room-form">
                                                    {this.renderUserInput()}
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>

                                    <div className="form-group  label-floating is-empty">
                                        <label className="control-label">Document</label>
                                        <FileUploader
                                            accept="pdf,doc/*"
                                            name="avatar"
                                            randomizeFilename
                                            storageRef={DbConfig.storage().ref('upload/')}
                                            onUploadStart={this.handlePdfUploadStart}
                                            onUploadError={this.handlePdfUploadError}
                                            onUploadSuccess={this.handlePdfUploadSuccess}
                                        />
                                        <img src={this.state.avatarURL}/>                                    
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-fill btn-rose submit_btn">Submit</button>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Use arrow function. handlePdfUploadSuccess = (filename) => { // task}. Then only this.state will refer to you component's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `handlePdfUploadSuccess`, as an event handler, has its own `this` context. You can get the component's `this` context by turning `handlePdfUploadSuccess` to an arrow function, like this:

```
handlePdfUploadSuccess = filename => {

    alert(filename);

    this.setState({ avatar: filename, progress: 100, isUploading: false }); //error line
    DbConfig.storage().ref('upload/').child(filename).getDownloadURL().then(url => this.setState({ avatarURL: url }));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Added modified `handleSubmitFirebase` function as an example for saving new entry in the database:

```
handleSubmitFirebase(event) {
    alert(this.state.avatarURL);
    var newEntry = DbConfig.database().ref("documents").push()
    var docInfo = {
        title: this.docnm.value,
        path: this.state.avatarURL,
        document_type: this.doc_type.value,
        unm: this.unm.value,
        D_id: newEntry.key
    }; //documents info
    newEntry.set(docInfo);
    this.docnm.value = ""; // <- clear the input
    alert("Successfully Added");
}
```

Comment: yeah my error had been resolved ,but it does not save into my database

Comment: Can you show me the code you would use to save the URL to the database? It should probably go in this function too.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what's the error you're getting now? I understand state is being correctly set now, right? Although I already see a potential problem, you're referencing a `docinfo` from the very object declaration, when it's still undefined: `D_id: DbConfig.database().ref("documents").push(docInfo).key`. I think you should get the key first, using this: `D_id: DbConfig.database().ref("documents").push().key`. And then update the new entry like this: `DbConfig.database().ref("documents").update(docInfo)`

Comment: i don't get any error.Yes state is set now and `D_id: DbConfig.database().ref("documents").push(docInfo).key` will generate key for that record. but i don't understand if all things are perfect at their place that why don't it saved to database. I dont want to updated instead i wanted to add this record with file path.

Comment: But you're trying to define the `docInfo` object `key` property with a call that uses the same `docInfo` that is yet undefined. I'll update my code above to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to fix this error. The problem being the context.
Either you do (in the constructor):

```
this.handlePdfUploadSuccess = this.handlePdfUploadSuccess.bind(this)
```

or you change your method to become an arrow function (which binds this to itself):

```
handlePdfUploadSuccess = filename => { // logic here }
```

or, in the jsx part (inside render):

```
onUploadSuccess={this.handlePdfUploadSuccess.bind(this)}
```

In terms of performance and bundle size, the first approach is the best. But it terms of code readability the second is preferred. Also, avoid the third way :) . Also, remove the `//filename={file => this.docnm + file.name.split('.')[1] }` from there, sometimes the parser doesn't like those comments inside jsx components.

Comment: thank you so much for such fine explanatiion.It really helps me